# creating new user for joomla in phpmyadmin

Tags: joomla, phpmyadmin

I want to create a new user for joomla as Admin in phpmyadmin . How can I create it and grant all privileges to it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the values in phpmyadmin with the following query.  Please adjust table prefix from jos_ to whatever yours is.

```html
INSERT INTO `jos_users`
   (`name`, `username`, `password`, `params`, `registerDate`, `lastvisitDate`, `lastResetTime`)
VALUES ('Administrator2', 'admin2',
    'd2064d358136996bd22421584a7cb33e:trd7TvKHx6dMeoMmBVxYmg0vuXEA4199', '', NOW(), NOW(), NOW());

INSERT INTO `jos_user_usergroup_map` (`user_id`,`group_id`)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'8'); <br/>
```

At this point, you should be able to log into the back end of Joomla! with the username of "admin2" and password of "secret". After logging in, go to the User Manager and change the password to a new secure value and add a valid e-mail address to the account. https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password

Comment: This answer relies too much on the hyperlink.  Offering a link to Joomla documents should be supplemental at most.  Please express the steps directly on this page.  Stack Exchange discourages link-only answers because of the page is moved or d8es, then your answer is rendered useless to future researchers.  Please update.

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO `yourprefix_users` (`name`, `username`, `password`, `params`)
```

***yourprefix*** - In configuration.php in Joomla root folder, you can find prefix for your database. In this case it will be `public $dbprefix = 'explain_';`

```
VALUES ('Administrator2', 'admin2', 'd2064d358136996bd22421584a7cb33e:trd7TvKHx6dMeoMmBVxYmg0vuXEA4199', '');
```

***Administrator2*** - This is name for your new user account.

***admin2*** - This is nickname / login name for new user.

***d2064d358136996bd22421584a7cb33e:trd7TvKHx6dMeoMmBVxYmg0vuXEA4199*** -
 This is MD5 hash password. Password is: `secret`

```
INSERT INTO `yourprefix_user_usergroup_map` (`user_id`,`group_id`)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'8');
```

**Make sure you match your db table prefix!**

Here is some hash password if you want to change

```
- password = "this is the MD5 and salted hashed password"
------------------------------------------------------
- admin  = 433903e0a9d6a712e00251e44d29bf87:UJ0b9J5fufL3FKfCc0TLsYJBh2PFULvT
- secret = d2064d358136996bd22421584a7cb33e:trd7TvKHx6dMeoMmBVxYmg0vuXEA4199
- OU812  = 5e3128b27a2c1f8eb53689f511c4ca9e:J584KAEv9d8VKwRGhb8ve7GdKoG7isMm
```

> Warning: The password values shown on this page are public knowledge
>   and are only for recovery. Your site may be hacked if you do not
>   change the password to a secure value after logging in. Be sure you
>   change the password to a secure value after logging in.

Full code for explain is here:

```
INSERT INTO `yourprefix_users`
(`name`, `username`, `password`, `params`)
VALUES ('Administrator2', 'admin2',
'd2064d358136996bd22421584a7cb33e:trd7TvKHx6dMeoMmBVxYmg0vuXEA4199', '');
INSERT INTO `yourprefix_user_usergroup_map` (`user_id`,`group_id`)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'8');
```

Comment: What will he understand from these codes? And what password is this `d2064d358136996bd22421584a7cb33e:trd7TvKHx6dMeoMmBVxYmg0vuXEA4199` . This seems to be a hex code, and whether he can enter this password directly to login. Give an answer with complete explanation or at least the user can understand something.

Comment: @AmitRay You are right, I edit my answer and give cimplete explain.